# Override fineuploader delete behavior?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fine-uploader

Iam using http://fineuploader.com/ and the delete function. When fineuploader delete a file, it displays a loading image. I do not want to show any loading image and instead fade out the image. How can I override fineupload delete function "design" with jQuery?

Fineuploader html

```
    <div class="qq-upload-list-selector">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <div class ="thumbnail">
            <div class="gallery-box">
            <a href="#" class="qq-upload-delete-selector caption simple-caption delete-single-image just-uploaded">
            <span class="qq-upload-delete-selector glyphicon glyphicon-trash"> Delete</span>
            </a>
                <span class="qq-upload-spinner-selector qq-upload-spinner-overlay">
                <span class="qq-upload-spinner">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh glyphicon-refresh-animate"></span>
                <span class="upload-photo-text">Uploading photo...</span>
                </span>
                </span>
                <img class="qq-thumbnail-selector" qq-max-size="250" qq-server-scale>
                <span class="qq-edit-filename-icon-selector qq-edit-filename-icon"></span>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Fineuploader delete

```
     deleteFile: {
         enabled: true,
         method: "POST",
         endpoint: url + "path..."
     }
```

My on delete javascript (jQuery) where I try to override the default fineupload delete behavior (not working). The delete function still displays the loading image and the picture doesn't fade out.

```
.on("delete", function(event, id) {
        $(this).parents(".thumbnail").animate("fast")
        .animate({ opacity: "hide" }, "slow");
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To react to an event when the delete is finished, subscribe to the `deleteComplete` event. The `delete` event is fired *before* the actual request is sent to the server and the deletion is processed. The `deleteComplete` event is fired *after* the response is received from the server even if the deletion was successful.

To remove the default spinner, just remove the relevant elements from the template. In this case remove:

```html
<span class="qq-upload-spinner-selector qq-upload-spinner-overlay">
<span class="qq-upload-spinner">
```

You could then, inside your handler, apply a class to the thumbnail element which would apply a CSS transition to that element. If the delete fails then you could simply remove that class and have it transition back.

I *think* your jQuery selector is incorrect too. Note that `$(this)` in the context of a Fine Uploader event handler refers to the jQuery-wrapped `HTMLElement`.

To add a transition, I'd suggest CSS transitions rather than doing them in Javascript.

```css
.qq-thumbnail-selector {
    opacity: 1;
}

.qq-thumbnail-selector .qq-thumbnail-selector-transition {
    opacity: 0;
    transition:opacity .5s, transform .5s;
}
```

Note that in the current version of Fine Uploader the entire contents of the `"qq-upload-list-selector"` is removed from the DOM when the file is deleted. If you'd prefer to react to this change and determine manually whether or not to remove the element then open up a feature request if you would like this to be considered for a future release.

Also, I would suggest you ditch jQuery altogether. It adds unnecessary complexity and performance overhead.

Comment: The fineuploader delete function deletes `"<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">"`. Don't know if you understand my question. I still want to delete but I want to change how it looks when a image is deleted. Fineuploader displays the loading image and fast fadeout. I don't want to display the loading image and a slower fadeout. I can't delete the "spinner" class from the html code because i display the spinner when I upload an image.

Comment: You want to fade the thumbnail of the image out before the response from the server?

Comment: I want to override how it looks when fineuploader deletes a file with my own style. I have tested with both `deleteComplete` and `delete` but same result.

Comment: This is explained in the 2nd to last paragraph. You can change the spinner for deleting items if you want, but you can't fade out it element when the delete succeeds. Have a close look at Mark's answer for details.